# SP2013 Creating item(s) in a subsite based on a multi-select

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, managed-metadata

Hookay. So I've just about exhausted my brain trying to figure this one out on my own and I've searched around a bunch and can't seem to find anyone trying to do something similar. So I bring this one to you.

I have a solution I'm building that starts with a document library at a site collection. A project manager creates a docset which holds project documentation and, at some point, indicates on this docset that there are work area impacts. For my purposes, I decided to use a managed metadata field called Impacts (but I could use a regular multiselect or anything else, honestly).

What I want to do is have a workflow that runs when those MM terms are added that goes to an already created subsite matching the MM term and builds a document set for the work stream in a document library in the subsite.
This works awesome if there's only a single impacted workstream. But multiple? Yeah, I just can't figure this out. I know this involves looping over the selections, but I can't for the life of me figure out how one would pull that MM field and count the number of entries.

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse the string value of the managed metadata field in a loop:

> Next, we count the number of characters from the beginning of the
>   string to the semicolon (I will refer to it as “DelimitIndex”) by
>   using the “Find substring in string” action. We copy the value up to
>   the DelimitIndex by using the “Copy from string, starting at 0 for 0
>   characters” action. At this point, we will have the first selected
>   value “TX | c61d9028-824f-446e-9389-eb9515813a42”
>
> Now, using the same actions, I find the number of characters (Index)
>   to the pipe (|) and copy the value up to “Index”. This grabs the value
>   that we really care for “TX”
>
> I trim the current value, just in case there are some extra spaces and
>   get “TX” as the end result. Next step is to add the current value to a
>   compounding variable “District” ([%Variable: District%][%Variable:
>   CurrentVal%]; – note the I add a semicolon at the end to delimit the
>   values. Any other delimiter can be used).
>
> I have cleaned my first selected value, I have to tell the loop it is
>   time to move to the next selected value. I add 1 to DelimitIndex. This
>   will tell me where the next selected value starts. I remove the first
>   value out of my initial “TempVar” variable by copying ONLY everything
>   after the semicolon (i.e. The second selected value). Now we just let
>   the loop repeat the same clean up routine. Once the loop is completed
>   District would like “TX;CA;”

https://ramirezmery.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/parsing-managed-metadata-columns-in-a-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow/

Comment: Ha!  I should have just waited to do the same googling I'd been doing on my work computer on a home computer.  That result from Mery Ramirez pops up but wordpress is blocked at my company and I'd since just edited it out of my mind.  Thanks!